# Shared Hosting or VPS Hosting for NodeJS app on Namecheap

Tags: node.js, express, nuxt.js, nestjs, namecheap

I have a Ecommerce Nodejs app that uses NuxtJS as the frontend and NestJs/NodeJs as the backend.Would Shared Hosting or VPS Hosting be better for this NodeJS app on Namecheap or any other service provider?

Answer (score 1):

I say, go with the shared hosting. Observe the performance and upgrade only if needed.